Decluttering scenarios on 737 MAX navigation display
The 737 MAX FCOM mentions an 'EXCESS DATA' warning that shows on the navigation display when there is too much data selected to be displayed at a time.

For example, this applies when you attempt to select terrain and weather at the same time. However, I am not sure of when this message will occur in any other scenario. I imagine it would appear when too many waypoints/airports are available in the current view (the MAX navigation display has a maximum range of 640 nautical miles so it does not sound impossible to me). However, I'm not sure of the specific number that will show the message, or of any other criteria that may apply. Does anyone have more information on this?

Not quite.  Selecting Terrain de-selects the weather radar display, and vice versa.  Maybe a bad flight simulator throws up the "Excess Data" message when doing that, but that's not when you get the message in the actual aircraft.
The first three mentioned switches (STA = navaids, WPT = waypoint triangles, ARPT = airports) put "things" on your map display, and when you've put too many for the display to handle, that's when it displays the Excess Data message, and not everything you've asked for is visible.  This most often occurs when you have both navaids and airports turned on at some reasonable scale like 80 miles, and then you switch to a much larger scale, like 320 miles: now the map has far more area that it's displaying, and instead of a couple dozen objects (navaids and airports) to display, it has hundreds, which would clutter the screen and presumably degrade the ability of the map to redraw as it should. So instead it displays the error, and you either reduce the scale, turn off some of the options, or both, and the error goes away.
The map on the Max is really huge, and it seems like it has a much "smarter" ability to declutter by not displaying as many "things" in the same geographic area at the large scale as it does at a smaller scale.  The Next Gen aircraft do this to some extent (i.e. ILS DME stations are displayed on the small scales like 10 or 20 miles, but not at larger ones like 80+ miles), but the Max seems to be able to just declutter so that you aren't seeing overlapping objects, even when you're looking at most of the western US all at once on the map.
